# How can I select the currently clicked div? and why is my function not being executed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I want my image to change when a different div is clicked, but the problem is I don't know how to detect which div was clicked, and that my function isn't being executed. Here is the code, and the W3 editor [link](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB215KOP5UZO):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#profile {
background-image: url("");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;

width: 304px;
height: 304px;

box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid white;

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);

transition: all 2s;
margin: 20px;
float: left;

image-rendering: auto;
}
#profile:hover {
//border: 2px solid rgba(101, 124, 226, 0.2);
//transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

#colorPicker {

width: 360px;
height: 300px;
//border: 1px solid grey;

float: left;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);

}

#colorPicker div {
border: 1px solid black;


}
#colorPicker div:hover {
transform: scale(1.2);
border: 1px solid white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="profile" ><a href=""></a></div>
<div id="colorPicker">
<!--ColourPicker's 30 nested divs will be made with javascript, let's attempt, as we'll need them anyways-->

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var link;
var bungie = "https://halo.bungie.net/stats/Halo3/PlayerModel.ashx?";

var race = "0";
race = "p1="+race;

var helmet = "9";
var extraDetails = "&p3=0"+"&p4=0"+"&p5=0";
helmet = "&p2=" + helmet

var colour = "0";
var extraColour = "&p7="+colour+"&p8="+colour;
colour = "&p6="+colour;

link = bungie + race + helmet + extraDetails + colour + extraColour;
document.write(link);

document.getElementById("profile").style.backgroundImage='url(' + link + ')';
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var cPicker = new Array(30); //here the color codes will be stored and assigned to each div
var divControl = [];

for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {//to create the divs to choose the colours for our spartan

    /*colour = i;
    extraColour = "&p7="+colour+"&p8="+colour;
    colour = "&p6="+colour;
    link = bungie + race + helmet + extraDetails + colour + extraColour;
    document.write(link);
    document.write('<br/>');  document.write('<br/>');*/


    var divColour = document.createElement("div");
    divColour.style.width = "16.38%";
    divColour.style.height = "20%";
    divColour.style.marginRight = "1px";
    divColour.style.marginBottom = "1px";


    divColour.style.backgroundColor = "red";//we have to get the color from the pictures, from the loaded links

    divColour.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    //divColour.style.border = "1px solid black";
    divColour.style.cssFloat = "left";

    divColour.style.color = "white";


    divControl[i] = document.getElementById("colorPicker").appendChild(divColour);
    cPicker[i] = i;


    }




function divHover(event) {

    /*function myFunction(event) { 
    var x = event.target;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Triggered by a " + x.tagName + " element";
}*/

    var linkHover;
    var currentDiv = event.target;
    alert(currentDiv);

    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {

        if (currentDiv.tagName == document.getElementById("colorPicker").getElementByTagName("div")[i]) {

            colour = i;
            extraColour = "&p7="+colour+"&p8="+colour;
            colour = "&p6="+colour;

            linkHover = bungie + race + helmet + extraDetails + colour + extraColour;
            //document.getElementById("profile").style.backgroundImage='url(' + linkHover + ')';

            document.write(linkHover);

        } else { };




    }


    //var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
    //elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);


} 

document.getElementById("colorPicker").getElementByTagName("div").onclick = divHover(event);
divControl[0].onclick = divHover;

//document.write(cPicker); //now we can link the individual div's with the links if we ever need to


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

It's in the if statement that I can't do the test, in the divHover(event) function, I'm new to javascript, and I don't really get why it's not working or returning what I want. Cheers

Comment: event.target (which you have in comments in divHover(), will refer to the div that was clicked, so you can do things like event.target.id to get the id of that div, or event.target.getAttribute() to get any other attribute on it to help you identify it.

Comment: Cheers, that really makes sense, thanks bro :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I gave every box a unique id in this example. the end result is output of `document.write` (output of the `divHover` function)

```js
var link;
var bungie = "https://halo.bungie.net/stats/Halo3/PlayerModel.ashx?";

var race = "0";
race = "p1="+race;

var helmet = "9";
var extraDetails = "&p3=0"+"&p4=0"+"&p5=0";
helmet = "&p2=" + helmet

var colour = "0";
var extraColour = "&p7="+colour+"&p8="+colour;
colour = "&p6="+colour;

link = bungie + race + helmet + extraDetails + colour + extraColour;
document.write(link);

document.getElementById("profile").style.backgroundImage='url(' + link + ')';
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

var cPicker = new Array(30); //here the color codes will be stored and assigned to each div
var divControl = [];

for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {//to create the divs to choose the colours for our spartan

 /*colour = i;
    extraColour = "&p7="+colour+"&p8="+colour;
    colour = "&p6="+colour;
    link = bungie + race + helmet + extraDetails + colour + extraColour;
    document.write(link);
    document.write('<br/>');  document.write('<br/>');*/
 
 
 var divColour = document.createElement("div");
 divColour.style.width = "16.38%";
 divColour.style.height = "20%";
    divColour.style.marginRight = "1px";
    divColour.style.marginBottom = "1px";
    
    
 divColour.style.backgroundColor = "red";//we have to get the color from the pictures, from the loaded links
    
 divColour.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
 //divColour.style.border = "1px solid black";
 divColour.style.cssFloat = "left";
    
    divColour.style.color = "white";
    divColour.id = "halo"+i;
    
    
    divControl[i] = document.getElementById("colorPicker").appendChild(divColour);
    cPicker[i] = i;
    
 
    }




function divHover(event) {

 /*function myFunction(event) { 
    var x = event.target;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Triggered by a " + x.tagName + " element";
}*/

 var linkHover;
    var currentDiv = event.target;
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var checkId = "halo"+i;
     if (currentDiv.id == checkId) {
        
         colour = i;
   extraColour = "&p7="+colour+"&p8="+colour;
   colour = "&p6="+colour;

   linkHover = bungie + race + helmet + extraDetails + colour + extraColour;
      //document.getElementById("profile").style.backgroundImage='url(' + linkHover + ')';
   document.write(linkHover);
        
        } else { };
    
    
    
    
    }

    
    //var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
    //elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
    

} 

document.getElementById("colorPicker").addEventListener("click",divHover);
    
//document.write(cPicker); //now we can link the individual div's with the links if we ever need to
```

```css
#profile {
background-image: url("");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
background-position: center;

width: 304px;
height: 304px;

box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid white;

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);

transition: all 2s;
margin: 20px;
float: left;

image-rendering: auto;
}
#profile:hover {
//border: 2px solid rgba(101, 124, 226, 0.2);
//transform: rotateY(180deg);

}

#colorPicker {

width: 360px;
height: 300px;
//border: 1px solid grey;

float: left;
margin: 20px 20px 20px 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
-moz-box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);
box-shadow: 10px -7px 106px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.73);

}

#colorPicker div {
border: 1px solid black;


}
#colorPicker div:hover {
transform: scale(1.2);
border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="profile" ><a href=""></a></div>
<div id="colorPicker">
<!--ColourPicker's 30 nested divs will be made with javascript, let's attempt, as we'll need them anyways-->

</div>
```

Comment: Alex did it solve your problem? can you please accept it then. you know , click on the check-mark on the left of my answer

Comment: Cheers brah, I learnt a lot about javascript from this ;) this didn't work, but I found a way simpler way to do it yesterday, redid the whole code:

Comment: And it worked so well http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB3FB30TMC54

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Don't use `document.write` for debugging, but `console.log`
- Check the console for errors. You would have noticed the error concerning `getElementByTagName`: it should have an `s` after `Element`. You have this mistake at two places.
- A node list, as returned by `getElementsByTagName`, does not have an `onclick` property, so that can't work. Instead define the click handler on the parent element and then check which child was clicked in the handler itself
- You did not assign a function reference to `onclick`, but instead *called* the handler. That is wrong. You should just pass the function reference without parentheses. The event object is passed automatically.
- The comparison with the `.tagName` property is weird: on the left side of the comparison you'd have a string like 'DIV' every time, while on the right side you would have a DOM element (if the spelling was corrected). This of course is never equal. There is a shorter way to find the index of an element: `var i = [].indexOf.call(currentDiv.parentNode.children, currentDiv);`
- You don't declare variables, like *i*. This is considered bad practice and will fail in strict mode.

Here is some corrected code:

```
var race = "0", helmet = "9", colour = "0";

function buildLink(race, helmet, colour) {
    return "https://halo.bungie.net/stats/Halo3/PlayerModel.ashx?" +
            "p1=" + race +
            "&p2=" + helmet + 
            "&p3=0" + "&p4=0" + "&p5=0" + 
            "&p6=" + colour + "&p7=" + colour + "&p8=" + colour;
}

var link = buildLink(race, helmet, colour);
console.log(link);
document.getElementById("profile").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + link + ')';
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
var cPicker = new Array(30); //here the color codes will be stored and assigned to each div
var divControl = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {//to create the divs to choose the colours for our spartan
    var divColour = document.createElement("div");
    divColour.style.width = "16.38%";
    divColour.style.height = "20%";
    divColour.style.marginRight = "1px";
    divColour.style.marginBottom = "1px";
    divColour.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    divColour.style.boxSizing = "border-box";
    divColour.style.cssFloat = "left";
    divColour.style.color = "white";
    divControl[i] = document.getElementById("colorPicker").appendChild(divColour);
    cPicker[i] = i;
}

function divHover(event) {
    var currentDiv = event.target;
    var colour = [].indexOf.call(currentDiv.parentNode.children, currentDiv);
    var linkHover = buildLink(race, helmet, colour);
    console.log(linkHover);
}

document.getElementById("colorPicker").onclick = divHover;
```

Comment: Thanks so much bro, this really opened my eyes up, you know your stuff when it comes to javascript ;) I ended up going even simpler, here's the working version: http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FB3FB30TMC54 but thanks man this was a good lesson, you're like my teacher haha ;) merry christmass :D